# passing list item name from fragment to activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

i have a recycler view list item where i am sending static data in array list and trying to get the name of listitem to next acitivty

Homepageactivity -inside (fragment listview item)--> (item name)activity

i want to send text 1 to another acitivity
here's my fragment

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
 //.. body

    private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {

            DataObject sr1 = new DataObject("Test",
                    "fsdf", "dfsd", "fdgdd","sdfsdfs","dfasdf");
            sr1.setmText1(" fdfgd");

            sr1.setmText2("vgsdfgsdfgg");
            sr1.setmText3("gdfgf ");
            sr1.setmText6("gfdfgd");
            sr1.setmText4("dfgdfg ");
            sr1.setmText5 ("S1");
            results.add(sr1);

            DataObject sr2 = new DataObject("Test",
                    "fsdf", "dfsd", "fdgdd","sdfsdfs","dfasdf");
            sr2.setmText1("dfadfasd");
            sr2.setmText2("dfasdf");
            sr2.setmText3("dfasfs");
            sr2.setmText6("sdfsff");
            sr2.setmText4("fsdf");
            sr2.setmText5("S1,S2");
            results.add(sr2);
            // and so on 

        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: which variable you want to pass to another activity? is it sr1 ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: Create an interface and let your activty implement it.

Comment: @MithileshIzardar i want to send  sr1, sr2, sr3....setmtext1 ("dfsdf") to another actiivity as title text but i dont find any similar reference. dear Mike M i have referred that before but still stuck.

Comment: have you tried using Bundle ?

Comment: putExtra (String name, Serializable value) of Intent to store, and getSerializableExtra (String name) for retrieval. that may work i guess

Comment: yes,i tried bundle like this    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<Student> arraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");*/ but dont know how and where to fit in

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Activity1.java**

> Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
>
> intent.putExtra ("myData", arraylisttosen);
>
> startActivity(intent);

**Activity2.java**

> ArrayList myList = (ArrayList)
>   getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myData");